# How can I change the color of a BSOD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, colors, bsod

I know that its possible to change the Windows boot themes, and logon backgrounds...

Is it Possible to make an orange BSOD (or a OSOD)?

I'm trying to prank one of my friends, and I though this would be a great way to do it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the MS Sysinternals utility to change BSOD colours:

http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/Notmyfault.zip

You can also generate a BSOD with this utility.

Comment: Gotta love Sysinternals!

Comment: Are the colours set permanently though? Seems it's just at the time of running the tool.

Answer (score 2):

[Anecdotally](http://www.petri.co.il/change_bsod_color.htm), it seems it was possible to change the colors of Windows 2000/XP era by altering or adding the `MessageBackColor=` `MessageTextColor=` lines to the system.ini file. I don't have a system handy that I'd like to crash, so I can't test it.

Comment: I'm going to wait 12 HRS before I pick an answer.

Comment: Windows has a [keyboard shortcut](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139) for testing it.

Comment: @grawity yes, but that doesn't mean I'm keen on crashing one of my systems ;p

Answer (score 0):

http://www.petri.co.il/change_bsod_color.htm A bit old but it still might work?